# How to add jQuery code only to the node add/edit page?

Tags: 6, javascript

I'd like to execute some jQuery code on a particular element in the node add/edit page of a particular content type. Currently I do that by putting

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("node/add/CONTENT_TYPE") > -1) {
        ACTION;
    }
});
```

in the theme's .js file. It works, but I think the approach is probably not appropriate, as the test unnecessarily runs everywhere.

Could you please suggest an appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to convert your script to [be a behavior](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!javascript_startup_guide.html/6.x#drupal-js-api). Drupal will call defined behaviors, so document ready is not necessary.

Second, you can add this script to specific form pages with drupal_add_js and hook_form_alter.

1. [Use hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6.x) to hook into node add and node edit forms. You can do a check on the `$form_id` argument to ensure it is a node form.
2. [Use drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6.x) to add your script file.

Example:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (preg_match('/node_form/i', $form_id) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/script.js');
  }
}
```

This file will only load when these forms are built, so, you can also remove the line that is checking the window href in the javascript.

The code above is untested, but a general start in the right direction. This code can be placed in a custom module, or, if your admin uses the same theme, you can place it in the template.php of the theme. I strongly recommend a simple custom module.

**Edit**

I believe the form id is preprended by the content type in 6. So, to isolate it to one content type:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'content_type_node_form') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/script.js');
  }
}
```

Or you can use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6.x) to target specific forms too:

```
function mymodule_form_content_type_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/script.js');
}
```

Where `content_type` is the name of any given content type (article, page, etc).

Example behavior (mymodule/script.js):

```
(function ($) {
  // you can define multiple behaviors

  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule_behaviorname_one = function(context) {
    // this code should fire automatically when the page has loaded
    console.log('Hello!');
    alert('Hello!');

    // attaching to an element
    $("a", context).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('You clicked a link.');
    }
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule_behaviorname_two = function(context) {
    // this code should fire automatically when the page has loaded
    console.log('Behavior 2');
  }
}(jQuery));
```

More on JS in Drupal (there are some examples in here for 6.x): https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: I'm working on implementing your approach now. (Never created my own module before.) What if that element I'm targeting is a CCK field? https://www.drupal.org/node/726282 seems to suggest an issue.

Comment: I am not sure you need to worry about the field, you just want to get the script loaded in the page. After that, you can target js for elements with the standard jQuery selector.

Comment: The module will literally only consist of the hook_form_alter code, and the js script file. It will be a great entry point into both learning how to make a custom module, and interact with Drupal in one of its most powerful hooks.

Comment: The ID of the form is quite generic (`<form id="node-form" ...>`). How do I be specific to a particular content type?

Comment: The form id is not the literal form attribute - it is the Drupal identifier of the form. You can see what the form ID is by 'print $form_id; exit;' - or by using the devel module to debug.

Comment: Here is another question that is similar regarding understanding what form id is, even though it is for D8, it still applies: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/229641/57

Comment: Gosh replacing that inappropriate code of mine seems to require climbing quite a steep learning curve. I have to figure out how to use `Drupal.behaviors`, then a custom module, then the Devel module. Would it be possible for you to give me an example code in `my_module/script.js` and `my_module/my_module.module` if for example I'd like to display `alert("Hello World!")` when the node add page of a custom content type whose machine-readable name is `foofoo` is loaded?

Comment: Without a debugger it is virtually impossible to develop in Drupal (or any platform for that matter). Devel is a major help. Otherwise it is like flying blind. I will add an example behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much. As to the debugger, yeah I couldn't agree more. I managed to get by with just Contemplate and Views Custom Field for quite a long time. Looks like I can't avoid deeper stuff any longer.

Comment: For instance, you can figure out the form id quickly by doing `dpm($form_id);` - boom, next. No more guessing.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance for now... Where exactly do I execute `dpm($form_id);`?

Comment: Within hook_form_alter in your custom module.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience. I understand what's going on and what to do now, and feel much less limited about what I can do with the website. By the way a closing parenthesis is missing for the `$("a", context).click` block.